# Python + Selenium can't find element by XPath

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on the "chercher" button on the left of the page (middle).

```
url = "https://www.fpjq.org/repertoires/repertoire-des-medias/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recherche"]/input[3]').click()
```

However, it can't find the element. I copy pasted the XPath so I am not sure why it's not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's because required button located inside an iframe and to be able to click it you need to switch to that iframe:

```
url = "https://www.fpjq.org/repertoires/repertoire-des-medias/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recherche"]/input[3]').click()
```

Also note that using `time.sleep()` is not a good practice. You can try to implement [Explicitwait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead

Comment: It doesn't throw an error anymore, however, it still does not click on the button.

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recherche"]/input[3]').submit()` instead

Comment: Thanks, this works. Had found another solution to click on one of the options above and press enter, but this is more elegant solution.